# Strange error android studio 3.0 fix R.string

Tags: android, android-studio

There is here such a line of code:

```
this.intentReq.putExtra("android.app.extra.ADD_EXPLANATION",getResources().getString(R.string.mystring));
```

Here `(R.string.mystring)) mystring` is highlighted in red. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mystring file is present in string.xml if yes then try to clean your project Build-->Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you're importing incorrect **R class** for your string. Another probability, R class is not yet generated when you've adding the string. Or you haven't add any string value in your `values/strings.xml` resource file. After you've ensure everything is ok, try `Build->Clean Project`. If it still not working, you can try `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart..` as the last resort.